# The difference between using fstream constructor and open function

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I have a simple question about the constructor of fstream and the .open function.
Are there any differences between the following two expression?

## 1

```
fstream("file.txt",ios::app);
```

## 2

```
fstream fin;
fin.open("file.txt",ios::app);
```

For (1), I don't need to use .open function again right? Any functional differences between the two expression?

My second question is that if I left the openmode empty, what will be the default open mode?

Comment: I'm only going to answer your first question. Please only post _one question per question_. Besides, you can answer your second question with ten seconds reading your favourite C++ standard library documentation.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream

Comment: oh I search it on some website for my second question... is it ios_base::in | ios_base::out ?

Comment: Yes, it is, as the documentation I've linked you to says!

Comment: In your first version you missed out the *identifier* making a *temporary*. Did you mean: `fstream fin("file.txt",ios::app);`?

Comment: @Galik no... I'm just using the constructor of fstream

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no differences in terms of the state of the objects following your two snippets.

Why are there two versions?

1. The ctor exists in order to create `fstream` objects that are immediately  associated with a stream.
2. The `open` exists because these types of objects cannot be copied. Hence you cannot assign an `fstream` object to a different stream by writing:

   ```
   fstream foo('bblskd');
   // ...
   foo = fstream('skdjf');
   ```

(Note that this interface was devised before move semantics).

---

You can find the default open mode [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/fstream/).

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no differences there.

Answer (score 3):

> For (1), I don't need to use .open function again right?

That is correct.

> Any functional differences between the two expression?

Not that I can think of.

> My second question is that if I left the openmode empty, what will be the default open mode?

It is `ios_base::in|ios_base::out`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open for further details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question, but none of the answers are right in my opinion.

Both versions are the same. But the reason for having a separate open is for when you want to create your own class that inherits from basic_fstream. And you want to do something with the input to the constructor before and/or after.

```
class MoleStream : public std::basic_fstream<char> {
public:
    MoleStream () : std::basic_fstream<char> ("defaultmole") { }

    MoleStream ( const char *fn ) {
        std::string s = fn; s+=".mole";
        std::basic_fstream<char>::open (s);
        if ( !is_open() )
            std::basic_fstream<char>::open (fn);
    }
};
```

The second MoleStream constructor does stuff before and after the open. This might not be good practice in c++, but it can be useful.