# C++ - std::getline() returns nothing

Tags: c++

I have a C++ function that reads a .txt file, however, when I run it, std::getline returns nothing. Therefore, the while loop on line 22 does not run.

How do I fix this function to return a vector where each line is a different item in the vector?

The file I am reading from a .txt file that has two lines:

```
testing
123
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> readf(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    file.open(filename);

    // Check if file is open
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    std::string line;

    // Read the file
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        if (line.size() > 0)
            lines.push_back(line);
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: You attempt to open the file _twice_. The first attempt succeeds, but the second does not, and sets the stream into an error state. Hence, getline will fail (but your test for an open file will not).

Comment: Remove this line: `file.open(filename);`.

Comment: As a technical matter, `std::getline` returns a reference to the input stream that was passed to it. The problem is not that it returns nothing; it’s that the attempted read fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to invoke `file.open(filename);` because you already opened the file using the constructor `std::ifstream file(filename);`.

Invoking `file.open(filename);` after opening the file using the constructor causes the stream to enter an error state, because the file has not been closed yet.

See [The difference between using fstream constructor and open function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997807/).